# Intent and startactivity don't work on onclick() in recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Just toast works on `onClick()`, nothing else and I have made all entries in `AndroidManifest` too

`Intent` and `startActivity` don't work on `onClick()` in `RecyclerView` adapter whereas `Toast` works fine

Here's my code

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.MyForecastViewHolder> {
public Context context;

private LayoutInflater inflator;

List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

public ForecastAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data) {
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyForecastViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_forecast, parent, false);
    MyForecastViewHolder holder = new MyForecastViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyForecastViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyForecastViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyForecastViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SubActivity.class));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you say "don't work," does the app crash? If so, please post the error from Logcat

Comment: You should read [ask] ;)

Answer (score 2):

How are you going to know which position has been clicked this way?
You should change your clickListener to inside your onBindView method which can give you the clicked position and set it on your root layout.

something like this:

```
class MyForecastViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyForecastViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon3);
        yourRootView = (LayoutType) itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SubActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyForecastViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    holder.yourRootView.setTag(position); // get it after with getTag()
    holder.yourRootView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```